# Java - Alias for Field Names

Tags: java, gson

Say I have an Object:

```
Object A
    String field1 = "abc";
    String field2 = "xyz";
```

The json for the above is:

```
{
    "ObjectA": {
      "field1": "abc",
      "field2": "xyz"
    }
}
```

I was trying to create a new id for the field names before sending the json.  E.g.  "field1" to be called "f1" and "field2" to be called "f2".  So the intended output json is shown below:

```
{
    "ObjectA": {
      "f1": "abc",
      "f2": "xyz"
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to do this.  Can the above be done in a clean way?  Thanks for your help and pointers.

I am using gson.

Comment: Looks like annotating the fields with `@SerializedName` might do the trick ([link to documentation](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-JSON-Field-Naming-Support)).

Comment: Thanks @Mick.   I looked at the example and it should work.

Answer (score 45):

Use the annotation `@SerializedName("name")` on your fields. Like this:

```
Object A
@SerializedName("f1")
String field1 = "abc";
@SerializedName("f2")
String field2 = "xyz";
```

See https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html.

Comment: Thanks  @Jesper, for the help.   This should work for me.

Comment: Although the above works - @Jesper.  I have many Classes and many fields.   Ex.  "field1" many appear in multiple classes.   In the above method, I would have to go to every class and add '@SerializedName("f1")' to every 'String field1'.  It may become a maintenance issue.   Is there a way to keep the aliases e.g. "field1 = f1" in a Alias Class, and call it during serialization.   Just a thought.

Comment: Just wanted to close this issue.  The best way I found - was to define a constant class - with the definitions.  The constants can be then used in the annotations.   If the definition of constants are changed, it reflects on all annotations that uses that constant.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable solution, I don't know of any other way to store aliases. @userDSSR

Comment: how can i do it if I can't modify the code to add the annotation?

Comment: you can use GsonBuilder and add custom FieldNamingStrategy `  builder.setFieldNamingStrategy(new FieldNamingStrategy() {
            @Override
            public String translateName(Field field) {
                return field.getName().equals("list") ? folderName: field.getName();
            }
        });`