# Can I declare a variable with square brackets?

Tags: java, json, rest, api-design, objectmapper

I am writing a POST API where I need to form a payload as,

```
{
"questions":{
  "preferredAnswer":{
     answer[0]:"my first answer",
     answer[1]:"second answer"
  }
}
```

This needs to be mapped as a java object.
My questions is, Is there a way I can map this json to the below class? or Can I declare answers variable as `String answer[0]; String answer[1];` (This syntax is not allowed)

```
public Class Questions {
  PreferredAnswer preferredAnswer;
}
public Class PreferredAnswer {
   String[] answers;
}
```

How could I map the json?

Comment: You could use GSON and give it a custom name mapping function. That way you have freedom in choosing which names you map to which java members. (see [FieldNamingPolicy](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/FieldNamingPolicy.html))

Comment: `answers: ["my first answer", "my second answer"]` https://restfulapi.net/json-array/

Comment: But I think you should first ask yourself if you could redesign this JSON, because that is not valid and very unusual.

Comment: You can also use the annotation `@SerializedName` with GSON, see [Java - Alias for Field Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33457640/java-alias-for-field-names).

Comment: I don't understand why my question got negative ranking.. its a valid question and got a exact solution from @vijayavel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't declare variable with square brackets, however you can have your JSON property with brackets and map it using `@JsonProperty` annotation as below

```
public Class PreferredAnswer {
   @JsonProperty("answer[0]") 
   private String answer0;

   @JsonProperty("answer[1]") 
   private String answer1;
}
```

Note: You need to provide setter/getter for these private properties.

This will map your JSON into java object and vice versa.

Answer (score -1):

Java does not have native JSON support the way JavaScript does. You can use libraries (like GSON) to help you, or you can do it the Java way, which would involve building it with more code than this.

But Java does not natively convert from JSON into objects the way JS does.

Comment: This does not answer OPs question, nor attempts to solve the issue. Its a comment. Please read [answer], thanks.

Comment: Sure it does. It tells him he can't map it directly like he might in other languages. It then directs him to a library that could be used for parsing JSON, which is what he's probably going to have to do. The implication is he should learn how to use GSON if he wants to do JSON from Java. I would personally consider it going a little far to expect the answer to actually involve writing the code before he's even looked at all the examples associated with the GSON library.

Comment: You show him the direction, yes. But an answer is meant to **fully** solve the complete question. That is, including a complete code solution, for example. With enough details to understand it and possibly external links to dive deeper (as defined by [answer])